# Jbutton hangs when clicked due to action performed within

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton, repaint

So I have this one button in a class that extends JPanel:

```
startTSP.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

             scatterPlotPanel.findShortestPath();

         }
     });
```

And my problem is, that the method inside the actionListener (by the name findShortestPath() ), is one that has to constantly call repaint() on another JPanel. The problem is, that once I click the button startTSP, it doesn't repaint or anything. It just hangs until the method completes running (which can take a very long time given the input). The only time it repaints is right at the end. If it matters, I can post the method for findShortestPath() but I don't think it matters whats in it, because my question is, how do I get it to not hang and just carry out the method normally as if the method was called in the main class?

I'm sorry if the question is too vague, I will try my best to explain it if anyone doesn't understand (just mention so in the comments).

Also, basically what this method is doing is, permuting through an arraylist of coordinate points recursively, and finding the shortest path between the list of points. It is a simple brute force TSP solution.

Comment: Have you tried using Threads?

Comment: Just use a thread to start your long taking process.

Comment: Okay, I was expecting this answer, and thanks for the advice, but I'm really bad with threads... I've read several tutorials but i'm so lost... can you direct me to something easy to understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a long method executed in the event dispatch thread, it blocks the event dispatch thread, and thus prevents it from doing its job: dispatching other events, and painting the UI. This effectively freezes the GUI until the long method returns. So you must not have long, blocking methods in the event dispatch thread.

Use a SwingWorker to execute your long-running method in a separate thread. Or if what you want is simply a repetitive event to happen every N milliseconds on the EDT, then use a `javax.swing.Timer`.

Comment: Can you point me to a link to help me understand how I can go about doing this?

Comment: The javadoc explains it, with examples. Swing also has a tutorial, with an entire section dedicates to concurrency: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try using another thread for painting on the other panel. This way you will have two independent threads doing different jobs.

You can use signals for communicating between these threads.